# Does/ Will MVC support "ASP.NET Dynamic Data Project" sort of template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic-data

In order to support faster development, does MVC supports/ provides a template similar to "ASP.NET Dynamic Data Linq/ Entities"? Or if there are any plans in the future to provide this?

Comment: [check this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) article from Scott Hanselman and [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/14/new-asp-net-dynamic-data-support.aspx) from ScottGu. I think it may help you

Comment: thanks for the article link.. its quite helpful and informative.. but seems a bit old.. there must be something invented within these many years :)

Comment: no, i am looking for latest updates.. the blog is of 4 years old.. so things must have been invented in between...